# how to create a "do not ask again" checkbox in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, checkbox

I would like to add a "do not ask again" check button to a UIAlertView.
Is it possible to do it? How and where should I save the state of the check button? And how can I retrieve it when opening again the same view?
Thanks in advance

Comment: with some custom implementation of an own alert view it is possible to add custom content – like a `UISwitch` or anything, but the standard alert view cannot have such button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible,

One way to do this is to call a selector when this

```
@selector(didSelectDoNotAskAgain:)
```

and then have something like this

```
(void)didSelectDoNotAskAgain
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:YES forKey:@"DoNotAskAgain"];
}
```

from anywhere in the app if you want to check this, you can return the value by using:

```
(BOOL)shouldAskAgain
{
return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueforKey:@"DoNotAskAgain"];
}
```

in terms of the UIAlertView, you should use a UIAlertContoller (if using iOS8) and you can add this button to the Alert.

Comment: thanks.. I'm going to try it :) about iOS8. Is the UIAlertView not going to show at all or just discouraged? I found this https://github.com/jverdi/JVAlertController for having both compatibilities. Can you suggest me other ways?

Comment: UIAlertView will still show but it has been deprecated as of iOS8.

you can set it too look the same as a UIAlertView by using:

UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                    alertControllerWithTitle:@"Rate my app"
                                    message:@"Do not ask again"
                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];